# registration form into billing wooccommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to add registration form above billing in woocommerce. Username/logi, password etc. All form must be submited by Place order button. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wocommerce plugin in wordpress already has provided an option to allow user to register ... a password option is provided in the billing form which will create a new user.

You only have to set that option goto `Woocommerce->settings->checkout` , and disable **guest checkout** option.